# group by after inner join not working as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: a raw user information table called `user_raw` (a row per user in a company) and a separate user details table called `user_details` that holds the unique details and values in the `user_raw.details` JSON column.

```sql
create table user_details (                                 
    id numeric                                              
    ,key text                                               
    ,value text                                             
);                                                          
                                                            
create table user_raw (                                     
    id numeric                                              
    ,amount numeric                                         
    ,detail jsonb                                           
);                                                          
                                                            
insert into user_details values                             
    (1, 'job', 'doctor'),                                   
    (1, 'job', 'police'),                                   
    (1, 'name', 'John'),                                    
    (1, 'name', 'Angela');                                  
                                                            
insert into user_raw values                                 
    (1, 500, '{"job": "doctor", "name": "John"}'::jsonb),   
    (1, 238, '{"job": "police", "name": "John"}'::jsonb),   
    (1, 486, '{"job": "police", "name": "Angela"}'::jsonb);
```

So, `user_raw` looks like:

```
id | amount |               detail                
---+--------+-------------------------------------
 1 |    500 | {"job": "doctor", "name": "John"}
 1 |    238 | {"job": "police", "name": "John"}
 1 |    486 | {"job": "police", "name": "Angela"}
3 rows)
```

and `user_details` like:

```
id | key  | value  
---+------+--------
 1 | job  | doctor
 1 | job  | police
 1 | name | John
 1 | name | Angela
```

The IDs are all meant to be the same.

I want to produce a summary table that sums all the amounts per distinct user detail in the `user_details.value` column, i.e.

```
id | key  | value  | sum  
---+------+--------+------
 1 | job  | police | 714
 1 | name | John   | 738
 1 | name | Angela | 486
 1 | job  | doctor | 500
```

I tried to do this by the query:

```sql
select r.id
  ,d.key
  ,d.value 
  ,sum(r.amount)
  from user_raw as r 
  inner join user_details
    on d.id = r.id
  group by 1, 2, 3;
```

but that just summarizes the whole `user_raw.amount` column.

How would I produce the desired table? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables and aggregate:

```
SELECT d.id, d.key, d.value,
       SUM(r.amount)
FROM user_details d INNER JOIN user_raw r
ON r.detail ->> d.key = d.value AND r.id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id, d.key, d.value;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=78dcd95232cccf8a7806862ea1168503).

Comment: Thanks. I just worked out that I was joining on the wrong column. Thanks!